# Joint density of two dimensional discrete random variable

Tags: probability-theory, density-function

I need to show that the function 
$$f(x,y)=\frac{2}{n(n+1)},\,\, 1\leq y\leq x\leq n; 0 \text{ for other values of x and y}$$
where $n$ is a positive integer, is a density function for discrete random variable $(X,Y).$

To show $\sum_{x,y} f(x,y)=1,$ I tried to find
$\sum_{x=1}^n\sum_{y=1}^x \frac{2}{n(n+1)}$ which does not turn out to be $1.$ Am I making some mistake in wrting the sum?

Comment: "which does not turn out to be 1" Hmmm, why do you think so? What does this double sum "turns out to be", according to you?

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\sum_{x=1}^n \sum_{y=1}^x \frac{2}{n(n+1)} &= \frac{2}{n(n+1)} \sum_{x=1}^n \sum_{y=1}^x 1
\\&=\frac{2}{n(n+1)} \sum_{x=1}^n
x\end{align}

Can you show that it is equal to $1$?

Comment: Thanks! I found the mistake in the sum I was doing. I was writing $\sum_{y=1}^x=1+2+\ldots+x$

Comment: Also, the points lie in a right triangle, $n$ points wide and $n$ points heigh, so there are $\tfrac{n(n+1)}{2}$ of them.